# QThread crashes QGIS

Tags: pyqt, data-frame, qthread

I'm trying to use a QThread for CSV export that can freeze my UI. Therefore I have a polyvalent Thread class below :

```py
class Thread(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.finished.emit()
```

which I use for this class :

```py
class Exporter:
    def __init__(self, df, filename):
        self.df = df
        self.filename = filename

    def csv(self):
        thread = Thread(self.df.to_csv, path_or_buf=self.filename, sep=";")
        thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)
        thread.start()
```

But when I connect it to my plugin :

```py
class TrajectoImportDialog(QDialog)
    ...
    self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.create_csv)

    def create_csv(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Export CSV", self.dirname,
                                                  "CSV (*.csv)", options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

        if filename:
            df = self.pandas_model.dataframe()
            exporter = Exporter(df, filename)
            exporter.csv()
```

QGIS crashes constantly. I read several topics with common issues like handling QWidgets inside QThreads. But the problem doesn't seem to be the UI. My data is stored in a `QAbstractTableModel` during the user process, then I export it to variable `dt`and the associated pandas method is `dt.to_csv`.

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday with a QgsTask? I can't find that question anymore, could you link to it?

Comment: No it's the first time I ask about this subject.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Are the crashes fixed if you do `Thread(..., parent=self)` and also include that in the `super()` call? Your objects might be garbage collected in the wrong moments. See if running QGIS in a terminal gives you helpful crash messages.

Comment: Because I get an error : `super().__init__(self) RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type Thread was never called`when adding it to `super().__init__(self)`

Comment: When running my code via qgis in terminal, I get `Fatal: QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`

Comment: Could you turn this into a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: The solution to my problem was the decorator of my `run` function in the Thread class. When transmitting different types of signal (as it is my case here), I needed to multiply the decorators with corresponding types : `@pyqtSlot()` and `@pyqtSlot(int)`.

Comment: Ah! Could you turn that into an answer and mark this question solved then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was the decorator of my run function in the Thread class. When transmitting different types of signal (as it is my case here), I needed to multiply the decorators with corresponding types : @pyqtSlot() and @pyqtSlot(int).